# Should I use camelCase for oauth2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oauth-2.0, nestjs

So i'm trying to implement an oauth2 server in nestjs and i've been reading the specification [[RFC 6749]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)
In the spec, all the query parameter names and even json response use snake_case like.

```
access_token
refresh_token
client_id
client_secret
redirect_uri
expires_in
```

The problem is, all the rest of my codebase use camelCase and using snake_case for a bunch of oauth related classes would make these inconsistent with rest of the code base.

So, should I change all oauth parameters to camelCase or would that be considered "Not conforming to specification".

Comment: just be consistent.

Comment: @karlan No, don't "just be consistent". The specification is `access_token`, and **any other spelling** is incorrect, including `accessToken` or `AccessToken` or `accesstoken`. You can't rename things and still be implementing OAuth2.

Comment: Ok. You're right. I was too quick to answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameters are required to be spelled exactly as defined in the specification, you can't arbitrarily rename them and still be conforming to the specification.

`accessToken` is a *completely different parameter* than `access_token`, and any client implementing the specification will expect you to use the correct name, `access_token`, as defined in the spec. Serving up a parameter called `accessToken` is no different than serving up a parameter called `foobar`, as far as clients are concerned.